# Tableview reloadRowsAtIndexPaths gain to 50% CPU Memory?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiviewanimation, nsindexpath

I have an issue where I have a UITableViewController and when the view appears I do some calculations asynchronously which should result in the updating of specific rows in the table.

Inside the cellStartEditing function I calculate the necessary rows that need to be updated as follows:

```
-(void) cellStartEditing:(templateRow *) row{
    int Cellowid= row.rowId;
    [arrQuestions removeObjectAtIndex:CellRowid];
    [arrQuestions insertObject:row atIndex:CellRowid];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: inSection:0];
    [tvQuestion reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

At that time reloadRowsAtIndexPaths Animation gain to  50% CPU Memory ?

Comment: Is this method accidentally being called multiple times?

Comment: Only Single time when clicked on cell index..

Comment: If you provide `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method code, that would be more clear, why this happens.

Comment: [tvQuestion cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]; but table not reload  at index.

Answer (score 1):

Notify about tableview updates before reloading the rows as below:

```
[tvQuestion beginUpdates];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow: inSection:0];
[tvQuestion reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]
[tvQuestion endUpdates];
```

Comment: If i have to use 200 rows than not gain memory but after 200 - 1000 Animation gain memory

Comment: Hope you are using Reusable cells , that would release memory.

Comment: customeCellAnswer *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; but Which type release memory ?